# Passing string with blank space ajax/php

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, get

I barely managed to put this code together to work just to realize that user can pass string with empty space, for instance "New York", which cuts the string and send "New" only. I've tried to encapsulate url with escape but it didn't work. Can someone suggest the solution, thanks...

```
<input class="field" id="locality"
              onfocus="City(this.value)"></input>

function City(city){

   $("#content").load("script.php?city="+city);

   //PAGE NUMBER onClick FUNCTION
   $(".page").live("click", function(){
     var page = $(this).attr("id");
     $("#content").load("script.php?city="+city+"&page="+page);
   });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `encodeURIComponent()`?

Comment: Nope, I'll try it... Since I'm passing it to php GET, I should be able to decode it with urldecode?

Comment: You should, not sure though